# Downloading older NDKs on a mac

Tags: android, android-ndk

Although i have found various methods to download a older NDK, it doesn't really work. With it I can download the past NDK (r10c).

I would like to download r7c because it is suggested in this tutorial right here: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ and mine does not seem to work by me because the NDK is not creating a file 
(so called "allheaders.h") (pretty much last question on blog).

So my Question is are there more possibilities to get a older NDK instead of changing the download URL?

Comment: Maybe you should follow a more updated tutorial. Always use the latest version of development tool / library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [android-ndk-r7c-darwin-x86.tar.bz2](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7c-darwin-x86.tar.bz2) link to get NDK r7c.

Njoy.

Comment: This link is for mac devices